How can i fix the error on " Error line 191! Missing number, treated as zero.< to be read again>\I@English.1.191|Idf@finish\currentoption"
I need help. My text in Miktex + texmaker end on line 40 but I  get an "Error line 191! Missing number, treated as zero.  \I@English. 1.191\Idf@finish\currentOption". please help me to fix this error.

This might come from something other than your .tex file, something that has more than 40 lines, e.g. some .sty-file from a package loaded via \usepackage.  As long as you don't provide sufficient information, e.g., the code for reproducing the erroneous behavior by compiling, and TeX engine in use, and version of the TeX distribution in use, one cannot reproduce and track down things and thus cannot tell you how to fix things.

\I@English looks rather suspicious have you specified English rather than english or USenglish  and I rather than l somewhere?

\ldf@finish\currentOption is line 191 of english.ldf.
